# react keep data in sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a real-time filter structure on a page. The data from my inputs are kept in my State but also as a URL query so that when someone opens the page with filters in the URL the right filters are already selected.

I'm struggling to find a stable way to keep these 2 in sync. Currently, I'm getting the data from my URL on load and setting the data in my URL whenever I change my state, but this structure makes it virtually impossible to reuse the components involved and mistakes can easily lead to infinite loops, it's also virtually impossible to expand. Is there a better architecture to handle keeping these in sync?

Comment: Hey,
Can you provide some code?
Can you also explain why you are saying: "it virtually impossible to reuse the components involved"

Comment: @nimzur kind of hard to include code since that'd be a lot of code for a conceptual question. Component reuse is difficult since there's not a single source of truth to get the data from so the structure is kind of convoluted.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you should calculate the url inside of the `render`.

Comment: Ok, my opinion would be to get the filters from the URL only when the component mounts (to avoid infinite loops), and store them in the state. When the filters change, you should have a function that updates the state and the URL at the same time. Also, to make your component more reusable, you should probably pass a list of filters it should be aware of, so that it will only modify those ones in the URL and leave the other ones untouched

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend managing the state of the filters in the view from query params. If you use react-router, you can use query params instead of state and in the render method get params need for view elements. After change filters you need implement redirect. For more convenience it may be better to use [qs module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs). With this approach you will also receive a ready-made parameter for request to backend.

Example container:

```
const initRequestFields = {someFilterByDefault: ''};

class Example extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.lastSearch = '';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkQuery();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.checkQuery();
  }

  checkQuery() {
    const {location: {search}, history} = this.props;

    if (search) {
      this.getData();
    } else {
      history.replace({path: '/some-route', search: qs.stringify(initRequestFields)});
    }
  }

  getData() {
    const {actionGetData, location: {search}} = this.props;
    const queryString = search || `?${qs.stringify(initRequestFields)}`;
    if (this.lastSearch !== queryString) {
      this.lastSearch = queryString;
      actionGetData(queryString);
    }
  }

  onChangeFilters = (values) => {
    const {history} = this.props;

    history.push({path: '/some-route', search: qs.stringify(values)});
  };

  render() {
    const {location: {search}} = this.props;

    render(<Filters values={qs.parse(search)} onChangeFilers={this.onChangeFilters} />)
  }
}
```

This logic is best kept in the highest container passing the values to the components.

For get more info:

[Query parameters in react router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters)

[Qs module for ease work with query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs)

[If you worry about bundle size with qs module](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=qs@6.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

This answer used *React Hooks*

---

You want to keep the `URL` with the `state`, you need a two way sync, from the `URL` to the `state` (when the component mount) and from the `state` to the `URL` (when you updating the filter).

With the *React Router Hooks*, you can get a **reactive** object with the `URL`, and use it as the `state`, this is one way- from `URL` to the component.

The reverse way- update the `URL` when the component changed, can be done with `history.replace`.

You can hide this two way in a custom hook, and it will work like the regular `useState` hook:

**To use *Query Params* as state:**

```js
import { useHistory, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'

const useQueryAsState = () => {
    const { pathname, search } = useLocation()
    const history = useHistory()

    // helper method to create an object from URLSearchParams
    const params = getQueryParamsAsObject(search)

    const updateQuery = (updatedParams) => {
        Object.assign(params, updatedParams)
        // helper method to convert {key1:value,k:v} to '?key1=value&k=v'
        history.replace(pathname + objectToQueryParams(params))
    }

    return [params, updateQuery]
}
```

**To use *Route Params* as state:**

```js
import { generatePath, useHistory, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom'

const useParamsAsState = () => {
    const { path, params } = useRouteMatch()
    const history = useHistory()

    const updateParams = (updatedParams) => {
        Object.assign(params, updatedParams)
        history.push(generatePath(path, params))
    }
    return [params, updateParams]
}
```

> Note to the `history.replace` in the *Query Params* code and to the `history.push` in the *Route Params* code.

**Usage:** (Not a real component from my code, sorry if there are compilation issues)

```js
const ExampleComponent = () => {
    const [{ user }, updateParams] = useParamsAsState()
    const [{ showDetails }, updateQuery] = useQueryAsState()

    return <div>
        {user}<br/ >{showDetails === 'true' && 'Some details'}
        <DropDown ... onSelect={(selected) => updateParams({ user: selected }) />
        <Checkbox ... onChange={(isChecked) => updateQuery({ showDetails: isChecked} })} />
    </div>
}
```

---

I published this custom hook as *npm package*: [use-route-as-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-route-as-state)